# Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I have huge delays on my project... I try to understand what is wrong and I can not find a solution. I get on my page these messages

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: controllers/help.php Line Number: 243
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: controllers/help.php Line Number: 244
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: controllers/help.php Line Number: 245

The lines 243, 244, 245 are as follows on my Controllers

I have created a space between the lines 243, 244, 245 for the image posted here

```
$this->template->write('meta_title',$school_details->title.'-'.$data['site_setting']['site_name'].' School-'.$meta['title'], TRUE);
        $this->template->write('meta_description', $school_details->title.'-'.$data['site_setting']['site_name'].' School-'.$meta['meta_description'], TRUE);
        $this->template->write('meta_keyword', $school_details->title.'-'.$data['site_setting']['site_name'].' School-'.$meta['meta_keyword'], TRUE);
```

on my URL further down I get
also another error which is

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: default/school_detail.php Line Number: 11
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: default/school_detail.php Line
>   Number: 14

Now pages 11 to 18 are as follows on my views

```
<div class="faq_list_div">


            <h3 class="faq_heading_title"><?php echo $school_details->title; ?></h3>

            <div style="padding-top:13px;">
            <?php $content=$school_details->description;
                $content=str_replace('KSYDOU','"',$content);
                $content=str_replace('KSYSING',"'",$content); 

                echo $content; ?>
            </div>
```

What is happening? The parameters work well (in English) when i use Greek Language 
is another story although is on UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$school_details` is an object? If it is not set, or not an object, this error will occur.

Comment: Yes $school_details it is an object.

Comment: school_detail is an object (without an s at the end) what should I do? i have tried changes but I always came to a wall nothing happens or the problem multiplies... Any help will be mostly valuable

Comment: (1) If `$school_detail` is an object and `$school_details` with an s, is not a variable, then remove the s at the end that you have placed in your above code snippet (the variable name is wrong). (2) Are you sure `$school_details` is not an array? If it is an array, use `$school_details['title']` for example instead of `$school_details->title`.

Comment: I will have a look at it but I have the feeling that the problem maybe caused by the language stream for a reason when I write text in English language then I do not have a problem but when I insert Greek language text then I have a problem... and then the error appears... any ideas... of how, where and what should I do? Thanks Aiias